# Drag using Pan gesture in flex android app

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, flex4.5, air-android

I'm using flash builder burrito and i'm having a mobile application.Is it possible to drag an UIComponent using pan gesture event???.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the draging by using below.

When user onTouch UIComponent then make a condition

MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN   make it UINAME#.startDrag();
MotionEvent.ACTION_UP     UINAME#.stopDrag();

Comment: I dont think there is a event called motionevent in flex.

Comment: Can you please check the following link , hope it would help you out  http://www.thanksmister.com/?p=1151